# How to Animate Splitting Different Layers of an Image (product image) in Landing Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I want to animate the splitting of a product image when the user scrolls to the section. i.e. When a user scrolls down and enters the product image section, I want to trigger the animation of revealing the different layers/composition of the product. Like it is done here (scroll down to the second section after landing page):

https://simbasleep.com/

A pure CSS3 solution is preferred. However, any library solutions such as jQuery, GSAP, etc are also welcome.

Comment: Have you looked how they did it?

Comment: It's a simple sprite replacement

Comment: you can use http://scrollmagic.io/

Comment: Yeah saw that its sprite replacement. But how to they trigger on scroll position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scrollmagic lib 
http://scrollmagic.io/examples/expert/image_sequence.html

DOCS Example:

```js
// define images
 var images = [
  "../../img/example_imagesequence_01.png",
  "../../img/example_imagesequence_02.png",
  "../../img/example_imagesequence_03.png",
  "../../img/example_imagesequence_04.png",
  "../../img/example_imagesequence_05.png",
  "../../img/example_imagesequence_06.png",
  "../../img/example_imagesequence_07.png"
 ];

 // TweenMax can tween any property of any object. We use this object to cycle through the array
 var obj = {curImg: 0};

 // create tween
 var tween = TweenMax.to(obj, 0.5,
  {
   curImg: images.length - 1, // animate propery curImg to number of images
   roundProps: "curImg",    // only integers so it can be used as an array index
   repeat: 3,         // repeat 3 times
   immediateRender: true,   // load first image automatically
   ease: Linear.easeNone,   // show every image the same ammount of time
   onUpdate: function () {
     $("#myimg").attr("src", images[obj.curImg]); // set the image source
   }
  }
 );

 // init controller
 var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

 // build scene
 var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#trigger", duration: 300})
     .setTween(tween)
     .addIndicators() // add indicators (requires plugin)
     .addTo(controller);

 // handle form change
 $("form.move input[name=duration]:radio").change(function () {
  scene.duration($(this).val());
 });
```